# How to test message from CanCanCan in Rspec?

Tags: rspec, cancancan

I'm looking for way to test message from CanCanCan gem.

```
def my
  authorize! :my_words, word, message: I18n.t("messages.login_to_add_new_word")
end
```

Something like?

```
it "sets flash message" do
  expect(message???).to eq I18n.t("messages.login_to_add_new_word")
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `authorize!` method raises a `CanCanCan::AccessDenied` error, so you can test for that.

```
it 'raises error' do
  expect { my }.to raise_error(I18n.t("messages.login_to_add_new_word"))
end
```

Comment: I just need to change `my` to `controller.my`, because I'm in controller spec. Thank you.